# How can i use the multisite support plugin for october cms?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, multisite

I'm working on a project using October cms where i want to have a multi-site platform.I installed the the multi-site support plugin for October cms but i couldn't figure out how to test it on a my local host because they ask that the domain URL for each website must be a full URL, ie.: 'http://octobercms.com' Any suggestions?I had read the documentation of the plugin but that wasn't helpful for me.Any suggestions ?

Comment: Just test it on localhost with full domains. You can fake dns entries for a domain (like `example.com`) with your `etc/hosts` file on your computer (google it, file location depending on OS).

Comment: Yeah and also C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.Thank u